# logcat filter shows count but empty when selected

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt, logcat

I can see there are 4877 messages in total in my logcat but when I select the "All messages" filter, nothing is there.
[image]
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Of course, I went to DDMS and select my 1 and only device (a real handset, not an emulator) but it didn't solve the problem.

I can certainly view logcat messages using `adb logcat` command but it's very difficult to see compared to logcat in ADT.

Restarting ADT does solve this problem but it's happening way too often and you all know restarting ADT takes time.

Note that the "All messages (no filters)" filter is only an example here. The same issue happens to the custom filters I've created as well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always update that value when you clear it or if they get pushed out of the buffer. As long as you don't tamper with ADB or manually clear it it the 'No Filter' option should stay full though.